# clearTimeout() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a document **"1.html"** with an iframe that loads **"2.html"**

On both html I have this code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    window.top.sesion_timer = setTimeout(function(){
       window.top.f_cerrar_sesion();
    },2000);
    //si tocas tecla o clickeas reseteas contador
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(){   window.top.f_reset_sesion();    },false);
    window.addEventListener('click',function(){     window.top.f_reset_sesion();    },false);
}
```

In the parent document I also have this code:

```
var sesion_timer;
function f_reset_sesion(){
    clearTimeout(sesion_timer);
    sesion_timer=setTimeout(f_cerrar_sesion,2000);

}
function f_cerrar_sesion(){
     alert("cerrar");
}
```

When I click on the document or the iframe the timeout reloads but the interval is not cleared so finally the function f_cerrar_sesion is called, Thing that wont happen

Comment: Just a note here : Don't use alerts for this kind of debugging. It is a blocking method, so there will be no other execution while the alert is waiting for your response. Use `console.log()` and open up your JavaScript console. I'm not 100% sure what effect this blocking alert will have on your timers.

Comment: I think you should use `window.parent` instead of `window.top`

Comment: Yep I do it, but the thing is that I have overrided the alert function in the project

Comment: @ArunPJohny It does the same, and I need it because in the example I give Is only one iframe, but it is really executed in more iframes inside anothers, so it calls to the absolute parent

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

I have to check first if the document is the absolute parent doc to add the timeout, other way It would add one timeout per iframe so, final code would be this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    //start the timeout if is the absolute parent
    if(window.top===window.self) {
        window.top.sesion_timer = window.top.setTimeout(function(){ window.top.f_cerrar_sesion();   },1200000);
    }
    //if keydown or click we reset the timeout calling f_reset_sesion(), where the timeout is
    window.addEventListener('keydown',function(){   window.top.f_reset_sesion();    },false);
    window.addEventListener('click',function(){     window.top.f_reset_sesion();    },false);
}
```